# How does one derive the centroid formula for multiple shapes?

Tags: geometry, infinity, centroid

I know how to derive the formula for the centroid of n sets of finite points, each with $m_k$ points and centroid $C_k$. The formula is: $$C=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}C_km_k}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}m_k}$$

However, when the sets of points become shapes, I'm unsure of what to do. An intuitive way of thinking about it would be that the ratio of areas is equal to the ratio of points, thus yielding the new formula: $$C=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}C_kA_k}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_k}$$ Where $A_k$ is the area of the kth shape. However, I'm not entirely comfortable due to the presence of infinities despite knowing single-variable calculus and limits. Is there another, more rigorous way of deriving the formula above, or at least make my intuitive idea rigorous?

Also, I've noticed that quite a few questions relating to centroids have received answers using the concept of a centre of mass. If you can, please refrain from using some ideas in your answers, as I'm looking for a purely mathematical one. However, if this is impossible, then I suppose it's fine.

Comment: Your guess is right: for a continuous shape the sum becomes an integral and the number of points becomes then an area. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#By_geometric_decomposition

Comment: If shapes have different thickness, one should use not areas but volumes as $A_k$. If shapes have non-homogeneous thickness, then their centroids can be located not in their geometrical centers. If shapes have non-symmetrical form finding their centroids can be not very simple task.

Comment: "Center of mass" is a purely mathematical concept. It is what you get when not all regions contribute equally to a summation (such as is used in defining the centroid). In a sense, your first equation above is a center of mass computation, not a true centroid computation. $m_k$ is the "mass" at $C_k$, here arising from different numbers of points. Such weighted sums commonly arise strictly from mathematical concerns alone, not just from physical modelling.

Answer (score 1):

The term "Centroid" specifically means the "center of geometry". That is

- For $0$-dimensional objects - that is, a countable set of discrete points, the average of the point locations: $C = \lim_{n \to N} \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$. If $N$ is finite, the limit is not needed, but it is required when $N = \infty$.
- For $1$-dimensional objects - curves, the centroid is the center of length: Given a curve $\gamma(t)$ defined on $t \in [a,b]$, the centroid is given by
  $$C = \dfrac{\int_\gamma \gamma\,ds}{\int_\gamma 1\,ds} = \dfrac{\int_a^b \gamma(t)|\gamma'(t)|\,dt}{\int_a^b|\gamma'(t)|\,dt}$$
- For $2$-dimensional objects - surfaces, the centroid is the center of area: Given a surface $\alpha(u,v)$ defined for $(u,v) \in D$ for some $D \subseteq \Bbb R^2$, then $$C = \dfrac{\int_\alpha \alpha\,dA}{\int_\alpha 1\,dA} = \dfrac{\int_D \alpha(u,v)|J_\alpha(u,v)|\,dudv}{\int_D |J_\alpha(u,v)|\,dudv}$$where $J$ is the Jacobian of $\alpha$.
- For $3$-dimensional objects - regions in space, the centroid is the center of volume: Given a region $S$ of space, and letting $\vec r$ be the position vector,
  $$C = \dfrac{\int_S \vec r\,dV}{\int_S 1\,dV} = \dfrac{\int_S (x,y,z)\,dxdydz}{\int_S 1\,dxdydz}$$

These should be taken as definitions rather than anything that must be proved. Indeed, as there is no other definition for Centroid, there would be no way to "prove" it. Though, the similarities between the definitions hint that it should be possible to come up with a universal definition that applies to all dimensions, of which these are the results of applying that definition to various dimensions. This is true, but is very abstract to accomplish.

"Center of Mass" is used for weighted summing. If there is a function $w$ on the appropriate domain, we get the following definitions for center of mass, depending on the dimension:
$$C_m = \lim_{n \to N} \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n w(x_i)x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n w(x_i)}$$
$$C_m = \dfrac{\int_a^b w(\gamma(t))\gamma(t)|\gamma'(t)|\,dt}{\int_a^bw(\gamma(t))|\gamma'(t)|\,dt}$$
$$C_m = \dfrac{\int_D w(\alpha(u,v))\alpha(u,v)|J_\alpha(u,v)|\,dudv}{\int_D w(\alpha(u,v))|J_\alpha(u,v)|\,dudv}$$
$$C_m = \dfrac{\int_S w(x,y,z)(x,y,z)\,dxdydz}{\int_S w(x,y,z)\,dxdydz}$$

Comment: The reason the 3D definition looks different than the others is that I took the "ambient" space to be 3-dimensional. If you want to work in higher dimensions, then centroids for all lower dimensions than ambient pretty much look like the 2D equation, but with more variables. Note that this covers surfaces that are not flat.